# Spring Activiti workflow configure custom schema

Tags: spring, spring-boot, activiti

I am using Spring Activiti workflow in my project and the engine is generating their own tables to my datasource. How can I configure it to generate these tables to a different schema instead of my default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to over-ride default data-source for activiti.

You will need to add ***spring-boot-configuration-processor*** as maven dependency 
and you need to define data-source for activiti like :

```
@Autowired
private DataSourceProperties properties;

@Bean(name = "datasource.activiti")
public DataSource activitiDataSource() {
   return DataSourceBuilder.create(this.properties.getClassLoader())
       .url(this.properties.getUrl())
       .username(this.properties.getUsername())
       .password(this.properties.getPassword())
       .driverClassName(this.properties.getDriverClassName())
           .build();
 }
```

**For detailed steps for changing data-source**, **follow** [this](http://www.canchito-dev.com/public/blog/2017/04/30/integrate-activiti-bpm-with-spring/) **blog**.

Comment: interesting ... always useful to be able to change the datasource :)